# select only one checkbox from group of checkbox and make it required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a form where I need multiple selection field using checkbox like gender, nationality, marital status.
I want to make field required & select exactly one option from the options.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.check3').click(function() {
$('.check3').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
$('.check4').click(function() {
$('.check4').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
$('.check5').click(function() {
$('.check5').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
$('.check6').click(function() {
$('.check6').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-3">
  <h4 class="d-inline">Gender</h4>
</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check3">Male</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check3">Female</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" class="check3">Transgender</div>

<div class="border border-dark col-sm-3">
  <h4 class="d-inline">Marital Status</h4>
</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check4">Married</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check4">Unmarried</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" class="check4">Others</div>

<div class="border border-dark col-sm-3">
  <h4 class="d-inline">Nationality</h4>
</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check5">IN-Indian</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-7"><input type="checkbox" class="check5">Others(ISO 3166 Country Code)</div>

<div class="border border-dark col-sm-3">
  <h4 class="d-inline">Residental Status</h4>
</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check6">Resident Individual</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check6">Non Resident Indian</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check6">Foreign National</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox" class="check6">Person of Indian Origin</div>

<input type="submit">
```

I used jquery & repeat same code.
please optimize my code & make it required

Comment: Looks like you want [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Comment: This sounds like a job for...radio buttons!

Comment: yes job of radio button but the form need checkbox

Comment: Why does the form require checkboxes? Use the appropriate elements for the job.

Comment: You want checkboxes but you actually described radio buttons: `I want to make field required & select exactly one option from the options`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can write same as : (add attribute `name` same as `radio`)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.check').click(function() {
    let name =  $(this).attr("name")
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
      $('.check[name="'+ name +'"]').prop('required', false)
    } else {
      $('.check[name="'+ name +'"]').prop('required', true)
    }
    $('.check[name="'+ name +'"]').not(this).prop('checked', false)
  })
  $("#form").on('submit', function(e){
    console.log('submit')
    e.preventDefault()
    return false
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-3">
  <h4 class="d-inline">Gender</h4>
</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="gender" required>Male</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="gender" required>Female</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="gender" required>Transgender</div>

<div class="border border-dark col-sm-3">
  <h4 class="d-inline">Marital Status</h4>
</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="marital" required>Married</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="marital" required>Unmarried</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="marital" required>Others</div>

<div class="border border-dark col-sm-3">
  <h4 class="d-inline">Nationality</h4>
</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="nationality" required>IN-Indian</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-7"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="nationality" required>Others(ISO 3166 Country Code)</div>

<div class="border border-dark col-sm-3">
  <h4 class="d-inline">Residental Status</h4>
</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="residental" required>Resident Individual</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="residental" required>Non Resident Indian</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-2"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="residental" required>Foreign National</div>
<div class="border border-dark col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="residental" required>Person of Indian Origin</div>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Update** add required with checkbox

Comment: but can you make these field required so that user cannot submit without filling these fields

Comment: i 've edited it with required